# Why does wcf generated proxy derives from object

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

"Update Service Reference" generates partial classes which derives from object

```
public partial class Auftrag : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
```

How can i get rid ob the object inheritance (so that i can derive from an other class in a partial class)
I do not want to change the auto-generated code.

```
public partial class Auftrag : System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
```

I want to use the generated proxy classes as data objects inside WPF-ViewModels and therfore I want to inherit from a custom base class (which also implements IDataErrorInfo). I do not want to copy and paste the implementation for each partial class.

Comment: What you want to achieve exactly. Define problem statement correctly. You may need to check your WCF contracts.

Comment: You should look at achieving what you need via composition. You're going to struggle stepping outside of the garden like this.

Comment: @iwayneo Could you elaborate on what this struggling would be?